# accumulation problem after reshaping multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have x_train, which is an array belong to data waveform, with dimension (475,1501) and I want the final output (seg2) to be (1425,500). I tried the following code:

```
count=0
sega=[]
seg2=[]
for i in range (0,len(x_train)):

    sega = x_train[i][:(x_train[i].size // 500) * 500].reshape(-1, 500)
    seg2[count:(count+1),500] = sega
    count = count + i
```

But it complains with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-72281c805a83> in <module>
     10     sega = x_train[i][:(x_train[i].size // 500) * 500].reshape(-1, 500)
     11     print(sega.shape)
---> 12     seg2[count:(count+1),500] = sega
     13     count = count + i
     14 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `seg2` is a list.  don't index it as though it were a ndarray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seg2` is a `list`. it looks like you need to declare it as `np.array`. Like this:

```py
seg2 = np.zeros((total_count, 500))
```

Where `total_count=1425`.

You can also use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) in this way:

```py
seg2 = np.concatenate([
    x_train[i][:(x_train[i].size // 500) * 500].reshape(-1, 500)
    for i in range(0,x_train.shape[0])
], axis=0)
```